# Constraining block types in draftjs editor

Tags: draftjs

In draftjs plain paragraphs are given have a block type of `unstyled`, although draftjs does define a `paragraph` type. Similarly when pasting, the default block type for p or div tags is unstyled.

What is the reason for this design? Is there a way to instead use `paragraph` as the default block type for normal paragraphs?

Comment: It looks like this is on its way, see here: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/pull/205